# subscribed value not showing

Tags: angular, angular6

There is a drop-down list that the user can select on and based on that selection the details of that item get selected.  The drop-down list is in a component called function and the details are in a component called function-detail.

I'm using a service to pass the item selected (in this case function) from the function component to the function detail component.

What I noticed is that the first time the item is selected in the drop-down, the item and its properties are undefined in function-detail.  However, when another item gets selected in the drop-down list the item and its properties are defined in function-detail.

I'm not sure why this is the case.

Here is the code:

function.component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="functions">
    <mat-option (click)="sendChangedFunction(func)"  *ngFor="let func of functions" [value]="func.Id">
      {{func.FunctionDescription}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<div ></div>
<app-function-detail *ngIf="loadFunctionDetail"></app-function-detail>
```

function.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ShareAppIDService } from '../share-app-id.service';
import { FunctionService } from '../function.service';
import { FunctionWH } from '../function';
import { SharedFunctionService } from '../shared-function.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-function',
  templateUrl: './function.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./function.component.css']
})
export class FunctionComponent implements OnInit {
  functions: Array<FunctionWH>;
  appId: number;

  constructor(private sharedAppIdService: ShareAppIDService,
    private functionService: FunctionService,
    private sharedFunctionService: SharedFunctionService) { }
    private loadFunctionDetail: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedAppIdService.appIdChanged.subscribe((appId: number) => {
      this.appId = appId;

      this.functionService
        .getFunctions(appId)
        .subscribe(data => { this.functions = data; });
    });
  }

  sendChangedFunction(func) {
    this.loadFunctionDetail = true;
    this.sharedFunctionService.changeFunction(func);
  }

}
```

shared-function.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { FunctionWH } from './function';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedFunctionService {
  private functionwh = new Subject<FunctionWH>();
  public functionChanged = this.functionwh.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  public changeFunction(value) {
    this.functionwh.next(value);
    console.log('function from changeFunction service is ' + value);
  }
}
```

function-detail.component.ts

```
import { Component,  AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FunctionWH } from '../function';
import { SharedFunctionService } from '../shared-function.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-function-detail',
  templateUrl: './function-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./function-detail.component.css']
})
export class FunctionDetailComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  private functionwh: FunctionWH;

  constructor(private sharedFunctionService: SharedFunctionService) { }


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.sharedFunctionService.functionChanged.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log("above function assign is");
      this.functionwh = data;
      console.log("function app id is: " + this.functionwh.AppId);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: so have <mat-option *ngFor="let func of functions" [value]="func.Id">?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the service and function.component.ts to what is below and now it shows the console logs in the subscribe method in function.component.ts.  I'm not sure what the difference is with the original code and the changes I've made though.

shared-function.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { FunctionWH } from './function';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedFunctionService {
  private functionwh = new Subject<FunctionWH>();
  public functionChanged = this.functionwh.asObservable();
  private showFunctionDetail = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor() { }

  public changeFunction(value) {
    this.functionwh.next(value);
    console.log('function from changeFunction service is ' + value);
  }

  public updateNavigationDetail(value) {
    this.showFunctionDetail.next(value);
  }
}
```

function-detail.component.ts

```
import { Component,   AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FunctionWH } from '../function';
import { SharedFunctionService } from '../shared-function.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-function-detail',
  templateUrl: './function-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./function-detail.component.css']
})
export class FunctionDetailComponent implements AfterViewInit  {
  private functionwh: FunctionWH;
  private showFunctionDetail: boolean;

  constructor(private sharedFunctionService: SharedFunctionService) { }


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.sharedFunctionService.functionChanged.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log("above function assign is");
      this.functionwh = data;
      console.log("function app id is: " + this.functionwh.AppId);
      console.log("function code is: " + this.functionwh.FunctionCode);
      this.showFunctionDetail = true;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to replace click to change event

```
<mat-option (change)="sendChangedFunction(func)"  *ngFor="let func of functions" [value]="func.Id">
      {{func.FunctionDescription}}
</mat-option>
```

2) Also try to replace the `ngAfterViewInit` to `ngAfterViewChecked`

Try either of the above mentioned or both together. Let's see if it works.

Comment: when changing the event from click to change the console log didn't show "above function assign is" or "function app id is: 1", which it did in the click event after the 2nd item was chosen from the drop-down list. While leaving the click event and changing to ngAfterViewChecked, the console log showed the log comments "above function assign is" and "function app id is: 1" 9 times